# type annotation when I know to be ina particular case

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a function that reads a JSON file and returns either a dictionary or a list, depending on the contents of the file. Here is the function:

```
from typing import Union
import json

def read_json_file(filename)->Union[dict, list]:
    with open(filename) as f:
        return json.load(f)
```

I'm using this function to read a JSON file that I know contains a list, like this:

```
def get_name_list()->list:
    return read_json_file("name_list.json")        <-- problematic line
```

My issue is that the static type checker (pyright for the record) complains that `read_json_file` could return a dict while the function `get_name_list` has to return a list.

QUESTION: how to say "I know that this specific call to `read_json_file` will return a list" ?

### Unsatisfactory solution 1

I've tried a couple of solutions along the lines of:

```
def read_json_file(filename, ensure_type)->Union[dict, list]:
    with open(filename) as f:
        answer = json.load(f)
    hack:ensure_type  = answer
    return hack

def get_name_list()->list:
    return read_json_file("name_list.json", ensure_type=list)
```

It does not work.

### Unsatisfactory solution 2

ChatGPT recommended me this kind of solution:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Union, List, Dict, Type
import json

T = TypeVar('T', List, Dict)

def read_json(filename, ensure_type: Type[T]=str) -> T:
    with open(filename) as f:
        answer = json.load(f)
    if ensure_type != str:
        assert(isinstance(answer, ensure_type))
        answer: T = answer
    return answer

def get_list() -> List:
    return read_json("name_list.json", ensure_type=list)

def get_json(filename):
    return read_json(filename)

foo = get_list()
print(foo)
bar = get_json("bonjour.json")
print(bar)
```

It makes the job BUT: the return type of `read_json_file` is not well readable. I prefer to keep `->Union[list,dict]` which is more explicit.

### Unsatisfactory solution 3

I can do this:

```
def read_list():
   answer:list = read_json_file("name_list.json") #type:ignore
   return answer
```

But it is not quite satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyright` won't complain about the following and it seems more straight forward than trying to ensure the type in the `read_json_file`:

```
from typing import Union
import json

def read_json_file(filename)->Union[dict, list]:
    with open(filename) as f:
        return json.load(f)

def get_name_list()->list:
    answer = read_json_file("name_list.json")
    assert isinstance(answer, list), "Wrong type"
    return list(answer)
```

Comment: Since the whole point of the function `read_json_file` is to read a json file with only 1 line in my "main real" program, I prefer not add the "assert" boilerplate ... but ...

Comment: ... but ... I can create a couple of wrapper function `read_list_json`, `read_dict_json` using your trick. It can even be clearer than `read_json_file`.

Comment: Glad it helped. Just remember that `list` on a `dict` will do the following: `list({"bar":"foo"}) --> ['bar']` so that's why the assert was there. Good luck!